# how to get the value from textbox in table and update it using javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, html-table

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
   
    <script>
    function m(){
var tb=document.getElementById("w");
        var len=tb.rows.length;
        var b=[];
        
        for(var i=1;i<len;i++)
        {    
b[ i ] = parseInt( tb.rows[ i ].cells[ 4 ].querySelector('input').value ) * parseInt( tb.rows[ i ].cells[ 5 ].querySelector('input').value );

        
    document.getElementById("w").rows[i].cells[6].innerHTML=b[i];
        
        }
        
    }
        
    
    </script>
    
    
</body>
</html>
```

I am new to javascript!I tried getting value from textbox in the table and updating the linetotal dynamically but i am getting the output as NaN.
can anybody corrects the error !!

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access `.value` on a table cell. You need to access the `input` field inside the table cell.

You need to be using `.querySelector('input').value` instead of just `.value`

```
b[ i ] = parseInt( tb.rows[ i ].cells[ 4 ].querySelector('input').value ) * parseInt( tb.rows[ i ].cells[ 5 ].querySelector('input').value );
```

I really recommend using jQuery though. It'll make life a whole lot easier! Vanilla Javascript is difficult to work with and maintain - even for the best developers.

Comment: can you edit the code to get me the correct one?so that it will be easy to understand

Comment: here's a quick modification to your existing code https://codepen.io/jamespoel/pen/dReNXW

Comment: Also, if you're planning on having decimal prices (e.g. 3.50), you'll need to use `parseFloat` instead of `parseInt`; if you use `parseInt`, it'll round up the value

Comment: Hey its showing an Nan in the linetotal ? how to change it to zero?@james

Answer (score 0):

```
function m(){
  var tb=document.getElementById("w");
    var len=tb.rows.length;
    var b=[];
    for(var i=1;i<len;i++) {
      var qty = tb.rows[i].cells[4].querySelector('input').value,
          price =  tb.rows[i].cells[5].querySelector('input').value;
      console.log(qty);
      if(qty != "" && price != "") {
        b[i]=parseInt(qty)*parseInt(price);
      } else {
        b[i] = "None";
      }
      tb.rows[i].cells[6].innerHTML=b[i];
    }
  }
```

You need to use `querySelector('input').value` instead of `.value`. I added a if statement that checks if both fields not are null and if so, the result will be "Null". You can edit the "fail-string" to whatever you want to.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: https://jsfiddle.net/abhiphirke/joq3jLk5/3/

Fill in values in fields and then hit `Click Me!` button. If you dont, you'd get NaN.
Have fun!!